# Error in starting rails server in local - Puma - runner.rb:103:in `reopen'- No such file or directory @ rb_io_reopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am facing the following error in trying to start the rails server, locally. The repository in the production environment working fine. Recent version from production is cloned into local. The only change was in the rails version in gemfile; changed from ruby '2.2.1' to ruby '2.2.3'. 
    Following the bundle update, this problem/error displays, on trying to start the rails server.

```
I am using a mac, the users directory is Users/circle. (issue could be related to puma version, rvm version and gem file versions). But any hints and suggestions in this regards would be greatly appreciated. 

[3951] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3951] * Version 3.2.0 (ruby 2.2.3-p173), codename: Spring Is A Heliocentric Viewpoint
[3951] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[3951] * Environment: development
[3951] * Process workers: 2
[3951] * Phased restart available
[3951] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[3951] Use Ctrl-C to stop

/Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:103:in `reopen': No such file or directory @ rb_io_reopen - /Users/circle/Test_new/testdirectory/shared/log/puma.stdout.log (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:103:in `redirect_io'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:40:in `redirect_io'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:408:in `run'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/circle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what is your command to start the server? Can post the puma config file here?

Comment: Had the same issue but with another directory. It is solved with `bundle update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the gemfile.lock, from the production environment, into the local repository did actually solve the problem. 
Post that, I have been able to get the rails server up and running at localhost.

It actually means, that for certain files the exact same version of the relevant libraries were required, rather than just the most recent ones from the gem file and bundle update. Since, Gemfile.lock was one of the files that has been included into Git ignore. So, it did not get updated locally upon cloning. It had to be fetched exclusively and replaced in the local repository. Bundle update, post that, had things running.

Thanks to all those who responded anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the error says

```
No such file or directory @ rb_io_reopen - /Users/circle/Test_new/testdirectory/shared/log/puma.stdout.log (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So I think you should create that file manually and see if that fixes your problem. On hosted platforms, there is probably an init script behind the scenes that does setup like this.

Comment: It might be that the `log` directory doesn't exist.